# How do I proceed with solving the wave equation using the sum of a forward and a backward traveling wave?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I am trying to solve the wave equation
$${\partial ^2 u \over \partial x^2}={\partial ^2 u \over \partial t^2} \ , \  x\in[0,1] \ , \ t \in [0, 2]  \tag 1$$

with the following initial and boundary conditions:

$$u(x,0) = 0 \tag 2$$
$${\partial  u \over \partial t} \Bigg |_{t=0} =h(x)=\Bigg \{ \begin{matrix}
k \ \ \mbox{if} \ \ x=0 \\
0 \ \  \mbox{if} \ \ x > 0
\end{matrix} \tag 3$$

$$  {\partial  u \over \partial x} \Bigg |_{x=0} = 0 \tag 4$$
$$ u(1, t) = 0 \tag5$$,

where $k=const$. I found some similar questions on the forum, but none of them took into consideration the boundary conditions, so I tried to find the solution on my own. However, I got stuck at a certain point. Here is what I did.

I wrote down the solution to this problem as a sum of a forward and backward traveling wave:

$$u(x, t) =  f(t-x) + g(t+x) \tag 6$$

Next, I imposed the boundary condition $u(1, t) = 0$:

$$ f(t-1)+g(t+1) = 0\tag 7 $$

$$ -f(t-2)=g(t) \tag 8$$

$$ -f(t+x-2)=g(t+x) \tag 9$$

Then I wrote down the solution as:

$$u(x, t) =  f(t-x) -f(t+x-2) \tag {10}$$

and redefined the conditions $(2)$, $(3)$ and (4):

$$ f(-x) -f(x-2) = 0 \tag {11}$$
$$ {df(t-x) \over d(t-x)} \Bigg |_{t=0}-{df(t+x-2) \over d(t+x-2)} \Bigg |_{t=0}=h(x) \tag {12}$$
$$ -{df(t-x) \over d(t-x)} \Bigg |_{x=0}-{df(t+x-2) \over d(t+x-2)} \Bigg |_{x=0}=0 \tag {13}$$

I got stuck at this point not knowing how to proceed. So my question is, what steps do I need to take to solve this problem?

Comment: It's possible to solve this problem using the method of images, but you have to manage an infinite number of reflections. In my opinion, the method of separation of variables is simpler in this case.

Comment: Can you refer me to some literature on that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, it is simpler to solve the problem using the method of separation of variables. Since this is standard textbook material, I'll skip many details. The general solution to the $1D$ wave equation $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$ with boundary conditions $u_x(0,t)=0$, $u(1,t)=0$ is (check!)
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[a_n\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi t 
+b_n\sin\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi t\right]\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x. \tag{1}
$$
The initial condition $u(x,0)=0$ translates into
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x=0 
\implies a_n=0\quad(n\in\mathbb{N}). \tag{2}
$$
Similarly, $u_t(x,0)=h(x)$ implies
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi b_n\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x=h(x)
$$
$$
\implies \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi b_n=2\int_0^1h(x)\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x\,dx\quad(n\in\mathbb{N}). \tag{3}
$$
Finally, using the identity $\sin a\cos b=\frac{1}{2}[\sin(a-b)+\sin(a+b)],$ we can rewrite $(1)$ (with $a_n=0$) as $u(x,t)=f(t-x)+g(t+x)$, where
$$
f(\xi)=g(\xi)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n\sin\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\xi.
\tag{4} 
$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply, though I am still confused about one thing. The orthogonality relationship integral $2\int_0^1h(x)\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x\,dx$ is equal to zero  because $h(x) = k$ if $x=0$ and $h(x)=0$ if $x>0$, right? Meaning $b_n$ is zero, so the solution to my problem is in the end just zero?

Comment: That's not surprising, as your $h(x)$ is equal to zero almost everywhere.

Comment: The problem is, numerically I don't get that the wave function is equal to zero. I actually get a moving square wave.

Comment: You can't represent numerically a function that is zero almost everywhere in an interval. Try to replace $h(x)$ with $$h_1(x)=\begin{cases}\text{$k$  if  $0\leq k\leq a$,} \\ \text{$0$  if  $a<x\leq 1$,}\end{cases}$$or with $h_2(x)=k\delta(x)$.

Comment: As a matter of fact, $h(x)=k\delta(x)$ seems to yield a square wave.

Comment: Hmmmm, this is a very valuable insight. Thank you!